# Possible with a backgroundapp that compares current pos with predfined pos?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Just a hypothetical question.

I am thinking of making an app that read the current GPS position and compares it to several predfined positions.
That is not hard but what I need to do is have it run in the background and if the device gets within a certain range of the predfined position it should make the user aware of that prefinded position.

Is this possible? If so can someone give me some suggestions how to think and do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with iPhone SDK 3.0 (as you tagged your message with), but you can with iPhone SDK 4.x  There's a section in [the multi-tasking docs](http://file:///Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone4_0.iPhoneLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4) that talks about doing this, including how to receive location events while in the background.